# How to check data in Backendless from Users table - Android

Tags: java, android, backendless

In my `MainActivity`, I first check to see if there is someone logged in. If there isn't, user is sent to `LoginActivity`. If someone is logged in, I check to see if the token is valid, if not, again the user is sent to the `LoginActivity`. If the token is valid, I then check to see if the user has completed the details on his/her profile. If they haven't, they are sent to the `ProfileDetailsActivity`. If they have, the code should continue and the user should be at the `MainActivity`. My issue is, when the user logs in, everything goes as it should. Since my test user hasn't completed the profile details, I am sent to the `ProfileDetailsActivity`. BUT, if I close the application completely and I reopen it, the user stays at `MainActivity` and is never sent to the profile details page. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Backendless.initApp(this, BackendSettings.APPLICATION_ID, BackendSettings.SECRET_KEY, BackendSettings.VERSION);

    String userToken = UserTokenStorageFactory.instance().getStorage().get();

    showProgressDialog();
    if (userToken == null || userToken.equals("") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        AsyncCallback<Boolean> isValidLoginCallback = new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(Boolean aBoolean) {
                if (!aBoolean) {
                    Backendless.UserService.logout(new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleResponse(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, BackendSettings.ERROR_SESSION_EXPIRED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

                        }
                    });
                    Intent intent = Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    BackendlessUser user = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();
                    if (user != null) {
                        boolean completeProfile = (boolean) user.getProperty("complete_profile");
                        if (!completeProfile) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileDetailsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

            }
        };
        Backendless.UserService.isValidLogin(isValidLoginCallback);
    }
    hideProgressDialog();
}
```

I have also tried moving this code block after `hideProgressDialog` and still no good:

```
BackendlessUser user = BackendlessUser.UserService.CurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    boolean completeProfile = (boolean) user.getProperty("complete_profile");
    if (!completeProfile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileDetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @Scadge I haven't. Where do you think would be the best breakpoints?

Comment: You should look where the logic goes the wrong way, that's what debugging is for.

Comment: still stuck? If you found the solution can u add an answer?

Comment: @BasanthVerma No, still stuck.